# C# Pass data between two Pages WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagridview

Im working on a small wpf project to understand c# and mvvm better.
Im currently having a problem, that I dont know how to pass data between two pages.
What I want to do:
I have two pages, they are the content of my MainWindow.
In PageViewCustomers I have a DatagridView(there are acutally two, but I just need one for this task), when I double click on a row, I open PageAddStaticIPAddress. Now I want to be able to access the row I double clicked in PageViewCustomers in the PageAddStaticIPAddress. I thought about passing the selected row as a CommandParameter in the xaml of PageViewCustomers.
But now I dont know how to access it from PageAddStaticIPAddress..
I have seen some solutions, but they all solve it by having Code in the View. I try to have as less code in the view as possible and solve it by only using Bindings,commands and my viewmodels.

Here is my current code:

PageViewCustomers.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="StaticIPConfiger.PageViewCustomers"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StaticIPConfiger"
  xmlns:localvm="clr-namespace:StaticIPConfiger.Modelle" 
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
  Title="Kundenübersicht">
<Page.DataContext>
    <localvm:VModel />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding}" >
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"  Name="dgCustomers" ItemsSource="{Binding AlleKunden}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,197">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=c_name}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Standort" Binding="{Binding Path=l_name}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateLocations}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItem}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Name="dg2Customers" ItemsSource="{Binding AlleStandorte}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,168,0,10" >
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding OpenAddNewIPAddress}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="StandortId" Binding="{Binding Path=l_id}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Standort" Binding="{Binding Path=l_name}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Class VModel.cs (VModel of PageViewCustomers)

```
namespace StaticIPConfiger.Modelle {

public class VModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    DataView _alleKunden;
    public VModel()  {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\WERBASWEB;Initial Catalog=customer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Dotnet123!")) {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select c_id,c_name, l_id,l_name, a_town, a_pcode, a_street from dbo.[AllCustomers]", connection);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        AlleKunden = dt.DefaultView;
        AlleStandorte = null;

    }

    public DataView AlleKunden { get; private set; }

    public DataView AlleStandorte { get { return _alleKunden; } private set { _alleKunden = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AlleStandorte");
        } }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    void UpdateLocationView(object parameter) {
        DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)parameter;
        string customerid = selectedRow.Row[0].ToString();
        string locationid = selectedRow.Row[2].ToString();
        DataTable dt = SelectStatements.SelectLocationsForCustomer(locationid,customerid);
        AlleStandorte = dt.DefaultView;
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    bool CanUpdateLocationView(object parameter) {
        return true;
    }

    public ICommand UpdateLocations { get { return new RelayCommand<object>(param => this.UpdateLocationView(param), param => this.CanUpdateLocationView(param)); } }

    void OpenIPAddress() {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new AddStaticIPAddress();
    }

    bool CanOpenIPAddress() {
        return true;
    }
    public ICommand OpenAddNewIPAddress {  get { return new RelayCommand(OpenIPAddress,CanOpenIPAddress); } }
    #endregion
}
```

Page AddStaticIPAddress:

```
<Page x:Class="StaticIPConfiger.AddStaticIPAddress"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StaticIPConfiger"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
  Title="AddStaticIPAddress">

<Page.DataContext>
    <local:AddCustomerVModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_net" Content="Netz:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_subnetmask" Content="Subetnmaske:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,36,0,0"/>
    <Label x:Name="label_ipaddress" Content="IP Addresse:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="text_net"  Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="103,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="text_subetnmask" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="23" Margin="103,36,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="text_ipaddress" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="103,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_description" Content="Bezeichnung:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="text_description" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="103,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_save_add_ip" Content="IP Addresse hinzufügen" Command ="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_abort_add_ip" Content="Verwerfen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>     
</Grid>
```

AddIPAddressVModel:

```
namespace StaticIPConfiger.Modelle {
    class AddIPAddressVModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    IPAddress _ipaddress;

    public AddIPAddressVModel() {
        _ipaddress = new IPAddress { Net = "", Subetnmask = "", IpAddress = ""};
    }


    public IPAddress IPAddress {
        get { return _ipaddress; }
        set { _ipaddress = value; }
    }
    #region"Get/Set"
    public int Id {
        get { return IPAddress.Id; }
        set {
            IPAddress.Id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IPAddress");
        }
    }

    public String Net {
        get { return IPAddress.Net; }
        set {
            IPAddress.Net= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Net");
        }
    }

    public string Subnetmask {
        get { return IPAddress.Subetnmask; }
        set {
            IPAddress.Subetnmask = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Subetnmask");
        }
    }

    public string IpAddress {
        get { return IPAddress.IpAddress; }
        set {
            IPAddress.IpAddress = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IPAddress");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I hope you understand my Problem ;-) 
If you have any questions, let me know. 
Thanks!

EDIT:
How I open AddIPAddress
I did bind a Command to the DataGrid, where I have a Command OpenAddNewIPAddress:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding OpenAddNewIPAddress}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

The command looks like this:

```
 void OpenIPAddress() {
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new AddStaticIPAddress();
}

bool CanOpenIPAddress() {
    return true;
}
public ICommand OpenAddNewIPAddress {  get { return new RelayCommand(OpenIPAddress,CanOpenIPAddress); } }
```

That another question I had. When I set the content of my MainWindow (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new AddStaticIPAddress();) with a new Page, the menubar gets lost... Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How do you "open" PageAddStaticIPAddress?

Comment: I edited my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject the AddIPAddressVModel with the command parameter. Something like this:

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Name="dg2Customers" ItemsSource="{Binding AlleStandorte}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,168,0,10" >
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding OpenAddNewIPAddress}"CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="StandortId" Binding="{Binding Path=l_id}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Standort" Binding="{Binding Path=l_name}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
void OpenIPAddress(object parameter)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext  = new AddIPAddressVModel(parameter as DataRowView)
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Content = new AddStaticIPAddress();
}

bool CanOpenIPAddress(object parameter)
{
    return true;
}

public ICommand OpenAddNewIPAddress { get { return new RelayCommand<object>(OpenIPAddress, CanOpenIPAddress); } }
```

---

```
public AddIPAddressVModel(DataRowView drv) {
    _ipaddress = new IPAddress { Net = "", Subetnmask = "", IpAddress = ""};
    _drv = drv; //keep a reference to the clicked DataRowView
}
```

Remove this from the AddStaticIPAddress view:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:AddCustomerVModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

The Page should inherit its DataContext. Setting the DataContext in the XAML markup is only useful in very simple scenarios when the view model has no dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I want to do ;-) I implemented your solution but I get an error message, as soon as I open the Overview: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedItem' property not found on 'object' ''VModel' (HashCode=30369281)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem='VModel' (HashCode=30369281); target element is 'MouseBinding' (HashCode=18183789); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

Comment: How do I inherit the DataContext? I always did it like this :/

Comment: It's inherited automatically provided that you don't explicitly set the DataContext of the Page. In the sample code I posted I set the DataContext of the window to an instance of the AddIPAddressVModel and the Content (AddStaticIPAddress) will then inherit this.

Comment: Works now thank you! Now I have a DataRowView reference in my AddStaticIPAddressVModel :-) I had to change the CommandParameter back to CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItem}". Is this a "nice" solution?

Comment: You mean the binding? It's fine. Binding to a DataView is a bit dubious though. You should probably define a Customer class or something and create an instance of this class for each row returned from the database and bind to an IEnumerable<Customer> instead of binding to a DataView. Then you could inject the view model with a Custom object instead of injecting it with a DataRowView. But that's another story really.

Comment: Ok thanks! Yeah I read about that, and I also have a Customer Class, but I thought it would be less work if I just bind it to the dataview directly ;-) Maybe I will approach this solution, to optimize it a litte bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a field in `AddStaticIPAddress`:

```
public DataGridRow Row { get; set; }
```

So you can access it from `VModel`. 
E.g. you can initialize `AddIPAddressVModel`on `DataGridSelectionChanged` action:

```
private void dgCustomers_OnSelectionChanged(...)
{
    AddIPAddressVModel addip = new AddIPAddressVModel();
    addip.Row = (DataGridRow) dgCustomers.SelectedItem;
    addip.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean DataGrid instead of dgCustomer? Because the class DgCustomer doesnt exist. In my xaml, I just reference the Datagrid by dgCustomer. So iput the field dgCustomer in AddStaticIPaddressVModel? Until now I just use it in VModel. And then in VModel I write the _OnSelectionChanged(Do I pass parameters here?), so I will be able to access the selectedItem in my AddIPAddessVModel?

Comment: Yes, if you want to send `DataGridRow`, but i'm not sure if you can easily access `DataGridRow` from your `DataGrid`